# Android DDMS exceptions?

Tags: android, exception

As i'm new to android, i really couldn't understand the errors or execptions shown in the android DDMS,I'm using Eclipse ..

Can anyone please share some very frequent exceptions that appear in DDMS and how to handle them......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should explain exceptions here for you? Maybe you should try to read the name of the exception... most of them are named understandable. And the very first thing you should do to learn about exceptions is to read their documentation: the very famous one for example: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

If that didnt help, try to search with google or here on StackOverflow...

Comment: can you please recommend some good sites were we can find some data that is useful for the beginners .

Answer (score 1):

If you opened any xml files, this error shoud occur. Close all xml files of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain but I'm also having the same problem. I believe it occurs when you try to call something that is out of context. For example if you tried to call
`TextView myTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);`
when you had set a contentView as something that did not contain 'myTextView'

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think this type of error occurred when you have edited the .xml file and rebuild the project.

If you have opened any xml files, save all the .xml files and Close all xml files of your application. 
and run the project. this way i run my application when this type of error occurred.